# Not getting device registration id from gcm

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my android application, I added notification service for this, I followed [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).
It gives this exception:

> "android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:"

How can I resolve this problem?

```
manifest.xml
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
</application>
```

Error log

> 12-03 12:01:40.868: I/PackageManager(585): Package com.example.gcm
>   codePath changed from /data/app/com.example.gcm-2.apk to
>   /data/app/com.example.gcm-1.apk; Retaining data and using new 12-03
>   12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585): Unable to retrieve gids 12-03
>   12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):
>   geandroid.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:
>   com.example.gcm 12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackaGids(ApplicationPackageManager.java:143)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:2559)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:2526)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startSpecificActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1066)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1633)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:1221)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishCurrentActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2482)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2415)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityStack.java:3360)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1953)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.forceStopPackageLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4507)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.access$300(ActivityManagerService.java:203)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$2.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:1309)
>   12-03 12:01:40.878: W/ActivityManager(585):   at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1848)

Comment: Also post your code and manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is not configured with any Google account then you will face this problem.
Simply add an account to it.

Also, try this in your manifest.

```
<!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="app.drugs.talksooner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="app.drugs.talksooner.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: My device had google account.check_play services returns true.

Comment: Is your account set to automated synchronous

Comment: Can you please explain what is automated synchronous.

Comment: Means is it set to Auto-sync. Is your account sync is activated.

Comment: Check out my edit too as well. You have not included <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

Comment: Can you please reboot your device and then add Google account to it. I faced same problem few days back and I resolved that as I suggested above. Let me know about that.

Comment: Again same problem.Rebooted my device and then added Google account to it.

Comment: Okay I will check this problem and get back to U.Till time check that on other device as well.

Comment: I checked on other device but  same problem